# How to pass a user entered form value from html to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

It is possible to pass a value from javascript to html by writing it to a  tag. However, if I would wish to pass a user defined value (etc, entered by the person viewing the webpage) to java script so I can do things with it, what would be the most easiest way possible?

At the moment, I have something like this:

```
 <div class="entry foreground-color">
     <form>
         <input type="text" name="commands" size="60"/>
     </form>
 </div>
```

How can I make the value from the form be passed to my javascript?

Or, am I going in a totally wrong direction? If so, what would be the correct way to get user input, and pass it on to javascript?

EDIT: Apologies for my misuse of terminology. I am making a text based adventure game, and I want the user to be able to type in a response, press enter, and have the response be sent to javascript, so I can use javascript to evaluate the response (etc "go south", "go north"), and write back to the  element with the new situation (etc "as you went south, you found a troll").

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing it. Do you want to access the input when the form is submitted or at any time?

Comment: by "passed" what do you mean ? Stored into a variable or executed like the eval function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just stop the form from submitting and get the value:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="entry foreground-color">
    <form onsubmit="return getValue('commands')">
        <input type="text" name="commands" size="60" id="commands"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function getValue (id) {
    text = document.getElementById(id).value; //value of the text input
    alert(text);
    return false;
}
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mPsz/)</kbd>

If you want to clear the box afterwards, use:

```
document.getElementById(id).value = '';
```

Like so:

```
function getValue (id) {
    text = document.getElementById(id).value; //value of the text input
    alert(text);
    document.getElementById(id).value = '';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, the form doesn't submit to a database, but as soon as the user presses enter the value within the input box is passed on to javascript, is that correct? Also, what do i do if I want to clear the  input box every time the user submits?

Comment: If I want to clear the input box after the value is passed to javascript (so the user can enter another value, for example), what do I have to do? In essence, I kind of want it to function like a linux terminal. You write something, press enter, something happens, and you write something again.

Comment: @user3367792 document.getElementById(id).value = "";

Comment: Thanks. This answer was answered perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The input value is already available for Javascript via DOM API:

```
document.getElementsByName( "commands" )[0].value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the *value* of your input control using:

`document.getElementsByName("commands")[0].value;`

Since `getElementsByName()` method returns an `Array` of elements with specified name, you will need to take the *first* element assuming that there is only **one** elements with `name` attribute `commands`.

Instead of that, for simplicity and uniqueness, i suggest you use the famous way to achieve that using `id` attribute and `getElementById()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="commands" size="60" id="commands"/>   

var input = document.getElementById("commands").value;
```

or

```
  document.getElementsByName( "commands" )[0].value
```

now do anything with this

Comment: `getElementByName` does not exist.  You are looking for `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an HTML element, first, you need to get the desired element (you can use theses methods):

- getElementById
- getElementsByTagName
- getElementsByClassName
- querySelector (moderns browsers)
- querySelectorAll (moderns browsers)

Theses methods depending on `document` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document)).

So in your case you can try something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    commandValue = null;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 if (inputs[i].name === "commands") {
    commandValue = inputs[i].value; // get the element value
 }
}
alert (commandValue); // show the value
```

But you need to set a "catcher" on the form default action.
So:

```
<form>
```

Become:

```
<form onsubmit="return getValue()">
```

And you set the javascript code above in the getValue function:

```
function getValue() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        commandValue = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     if (inputs[i].name === "commands") {
        commandValue = inputs[i].value; // get the element value
     }
    }
    alert (commandValue); // show the value
    return false; // prevent default form action
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path :)

For example you can do something like this (see http://jsfiddle.net/ahLch/):

HTML:

```
<h1 id="commandsExample"></h1>
<div class="entry foreground-color">
   <form>
     <input type="text" id="commands" size="60"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('commands');
var example = document.getElementById('commandsExample');

input.addEventListener('change', function () {
   example.innerHTML= input.value;
});
```

A couple of things to note:

- If you are new to JavaScript, and you wish to make your code cross browser (especially if you want to target old versions of IE), take a look to jQuery.
- If you wish to learn how to use plain DOM APIs provided by the browser without the jQuery layer, take a look to: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ (it's very useful once that you learned jQuery basics).
- There are a couple of ways to get the value:

  - *Intercepting from submmit event*: I don't recommend it, you have to take care of avoiding the default submit behavior, and you have to create a form around your input field. That was necessary in old browsers, but today is not.
  - *change* event: it's fired when the input value has changed and the input looses the focus (is the usual event used for form validation).
  - *keydown* and *keyup*: they give you more control, by capturing each keystroke, but it's lower level than the change event. For a complete reference see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent
- Use "id" instead of "name". Name is only necessary when you want to submit the value, in new browsers you can leave just input tag without a form.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to javascript, so let me explain what I can understand, and tell me if I am wrong: So, we first have a header that's blank, with a ID of commandsExample. This is where you are going to write the input to. Next, we have the input form, where we specify the input is text (?) and specify the id and size. In the javascript, you basically declare to variables that use document.getByID to search for html tags with a certain ID. The next part you listen for any new events in the input (?) and declare a function to set the input of the form to the <h1> tag (?). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of the input tag is quite easy with jQuery.
(I take it you need this anyway to actually send the message via AJAX to a server..?)

$("#idofinput").val(); will copy the value, $("#idofinput").val(''); will empty it.

You probably want to do this without actually submitting a form.
Recreating one in javascript isn't to hard.
For the submit on enter you can use something like this:

```
function checkEnter(e)
{
  var keynum;
  if(window.event) // IE8 and earlier
  {
   keynum = e.keyCode;
  }
  else if(e.which) // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
  {
    keynum = e.which;
  }
  if(keynum==13)
  {
    sendMessage();
  }
}
```